# Determine first and last Iteration in DatePeriod

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code that iterates through a DatePeriod between a start and end date:

```
//Start = 01/12/2023 09:50:00
//End = 07/12/2023 13:54:00
$test = [];
$datePeriod = new DatePeriod(new DateTimeImmutable('2023-12-01'), new DateInterval('P1D'), new DateTimeImmutable('2023-12-07'));

foreach ($datePeriod as $day) {
    $formattedDate = $day->format('Y-m-d');
    if ($formattedDate === key($datePeriod)) {
        $test[$formattedDate] = ['09:50:00-23:59:59'];
    } else if ($formattedDate === end($datePeriod)) {
        $test[$formattedDate] = ['00:00:00-13:54:00'];
    }else{
        $test[$formattedDate] = [];
    }
}
```

I want to populate an array based on the iteration, considering specific time ranges. The working hours at the office are from 09:00 to 17:00.

I need to identify the first and last iteration and adjust the array accordingly. The desired output should be:

```
Array
(
    [2023-12-01] => Array
        (
            [09:50:00-23:59:59]
        )

    [2023-12-02] => Array
        (
        )

    [2023-12-03] => Array
        (
        )

    [2023-12-04] => Array
        (
        )

    [2023-12-05] => Array
        (
        )

    [2023-12-06] => Array
        (
        )

    [2023-12-07] => Array
        (
            [00:00:00-13:54:00]
        )

)
```

The current output is :

```
Array
(
    [2023-12-01] => Array
        (
        )

    [2023-12-02] => Array
        (
        )

    [2023-12-03] => Array
        (
        )

    [2023-12-04] => Array
        (
        )

    [2023-12-05] => Array
        (
        )

    [2023-12-06] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

How can I identify the first and last iterations?

I'm using PHP 8.3

fiddle : https://onlinephp.io/c/9b183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I identify the first and last iterations?

`DatePeriod` already comes with properties `start` and `end` - so if you make it include the end date, with the`DatePeriod::INCLUDE_END_DATE` option, you can do it directly using those:

```
$datePeriod = new DatePeriod(
   new DateTimeImmutable('2023-12-01'),
   new DateInterval('P1D'),
   new DateTimeImmutable('2023-12-07'),
   DatePeriod::INCLUDE_END_DATE
);

foreach ($datePeriod as $day) {
    $formattedDate = $day->format('Y-m-d');
    if ($day == $datePeriod->start) {
        $test[$formattedDate] = ['09:50:00-23:59:59'];
    } else if ($day == $datePeriod->end) {
        $test[$formattedDate] = ['00:00:00-13:54:00'];
    }else{
        $test[$formattedDate] = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my desired output, 07/12/2023 is the last day.     [2023-12-07] => Array
        (
            [00:00:00-13:54:00]
        )

Comment: @executable ah, I was wondering about that slight discrepancy already :-) Wasn't sure though, if that was maybe intentional. Edited the answer to use the original `2023-12-07`. The important part is the `DatePeriod::INCLUDE_END_DATE`, to make the DatePeriod actually _include_ the end date, otherwise your loop would stop one day earlier.